# Go Reader.read(); how to get the contents without duplication?

Tags: html, web, go, buffer

I've started studying Go recently as a side project and have been trying to get a better handle around the Reader interface. Specifically, I'm trying to get contents from a website, and then reading it to a bytes slice.

I am aware that the ioutils.ReadAll function is the canonical way to get the data, but I'm curious why the original function I wrote has repeated content at the end of the output.

Code:
    package main

```
import(
    "net/http"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    // retrieve url from hacker news.
    resp, err := http.Get("http://news.ycombinator.com/")
    if err != nil {
        // handle error
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    text := make([]byte, 500)
    buf := make([]byte, 200)
    i, _ := resp.Body.Read(buf)
    for i != 0 {
        text = append(text,buf...)
        i, _ = resp.Body.Read(buf)
    }
    fmt.Println(resp.ContentLength)
    fmt.Println(resp.Status)
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", text)

}
```

Content:

```
         (...)Search:\n  <input type=\"text\" name=\"q\" value=\"\" size=\"17\" autocorrect=\"off\" spellcheck=\"false\" autocapitalize=\"off\" autocomplete=\"false\"></form>\n            </center></td></tr>      
         </table></center></body></html>\nput type=\"text\" name=\"q\" value=\"\" "
```

As you can see, for a reason I don't quite understand, one part of the text is repeated at the end after the closed tags; 'nput type=\"text\" name=\"q\" value=\"\" "'.

Maybe this is something related to the buffer not being cleared maybe?  Could anyone offer some insight as to what I am getting wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `io.Reader` interface returns the number of bytes read and an error value. You need to make use of both values.

The `int` return value shows tells you how many bytes have been read into your the buffer, and error informs you of error conditions as well as when you've reached EOF. A Reader may also return bytes read and an `io.EOF` on the same call, so you should handle that as well.

Also note that you create a slice for `text` of 500 bytes, but then you append to it, leaving 500 null characters at the beginning.

```
var text []byte
buf := make([]byte, 256)

var n int
var err error

for err == nil {
    n, err = resp.Body.Read(buf)
    text = append(text, buf[:n]...)
}

if err != io.EOF {
    log.Fatal("error:", err)
}
```

(Unrelated to Go, blocks of memory tend to work most efficiently when they are aligned to powers of 2.)

Comment: Thanks!  Just FYI though, I think you made a bug in the for loop (it should be "for err == nil" or else the loop will never run).